# Use transactional e-mail templates from local language package

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

How can I force Magento to use E-Mail templates from the local language package  in `app/locale/.../template/email/` instead from the database?

I opened one template in the backend in **System -> Transactional E-Mail** and made some changes which already worked but the content was saved into database in the table `core_email_template`. I would like to modify the html file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the solution I want:

My problem was I've installed a local language pack which has generated several custom E-Mails. These E-Mails were stored in the database. 
I simply had to change the used E-Mail in the specific setting in the backend.

For example in `System -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Create New Account Options` I've changed the option **Default Welcome Email** to **New account (Default Template from local)**.

This option (**Default Template from local**) will use the templates from the directory `magento/app/locale/.../template/email` and not from the database.

As addition I've followed the guide and installed the plugin from https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-theming/1670-customizing-magento-email-templates

So I simply can copy the templates to my own theme.